Python special characters not preserved on file write in 'wb'
I am having the problem in the following function:
def download_zip(key: str):
    response = requests.get('some url')

    if response.status_code == 200:
        header = response.headers.get('content-disposition')

        if type(header) == str:
            file_name = re.findall("filename=(.+)", header)[0][1:-1]
        else:
            file_name = f"{key}.zip"

        with open(file_name, mode='wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)

        print(f"Written: {file_name}")

    else:
        print(f"Failed: {key} -> {response.status_code}")



The URL 'some url' points to a zip file.
When downloading the file with a browser, its name contains japanese characters which are preserved:
音のないレプリカ.
With my code, they are not and instead produce something like this:
é³ã®ãªãã¬ããªã«. How can I make it preserve those characters?

Check the full contents of Content-Disposition header, specifically for field named filename* (with asterisk, it is not a typo). If you have both filename and filename*, the latter takes precedence, and it can use other encodings.

Good to know, but I only have filename: content-disposition: attachment; filename="some file 音の.zip"

This is non-standard, and I am curious as to what kind of server sent it to you. Since it is not really playing by the rules, there is no guarantee this will work in a general case. For your specific case, see if file_name.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8') gives you anything sensible.

Relevant standards: RFC2183: "Current [RFC 2045] grammar restricts parameter values (and hence Content-Disposition filenames) to US-ASCII." RFC6266: "The parameters filename and filename* differ only in that filename* uses the encoding defined in [RFC5987], allowing the use of characters not present in the ISO-8859-1 character set ([ISO-8859-1])." Thus, content-disposition: attachment; filename="some file 音の.zip" should not exist. The fact that it does is unfortunate.

file_name.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8') fixed it. Thank you Amadan! Also, if you please, tell me how to mark your answer as one. I don't know how to do that since I don't use stackoverflow often.

Case-specific solution: fix the encoding to what (you think) it should be:
file_name.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8')

More general solution: yell at the owner of the webserver to fix their headers, then properly set the filename* field of Content-Disposition. Then you could have some confidence as to what the correct encoding was.
